# How to store profile image to SQL server using web API in Xamarin Forms

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

How to store profile image to SQL server using web API in Xamarin Forms, Here I will get image using xam.plugin.media, I am totally new using web api in xamarin forms, I have login page filed like firstname, lastname, id, profileimage,emailid, phonenumber, My Quesiton is, i want to store profile image and username,pwd,etc using web api(Post Method), Please give me any suggesstion to resolve this issue

Comment: your image should go to the server as a `byte[]` or `Base64` string, i suggest you use `byte[]`

Comment: Here I have pasted User class below                                                                            public class UserRest
    {
        public double ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public long MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string DialCode { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public byte[] Profile_Image { get; set; }
    }

Comment: When I post UserRest from XamarinForms, I am getting profile image byte is {byte[2223346]}, This won't be any problem right

Comment: Not at all that is how it is supposed to be, see to it that your `POST` type Rest-API  can receive `byte[]` and you should be good to go.

Comment: When I Tried Xam.Plugin.FilePicker while i am getting error                             System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

Comment: You are using this in you Xamarin Forms projects PCL right?

Comment: Correct We are developing app using Xamarin Forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191093/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-p-thiyagu).

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to maeka one api call that save image as a string and convert string into bytes array I give example below.

```
FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
if (filedata != null)
{
    Data.Text = filedata.FileName;
    byte[] a = filedata.DataArray;
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(filedata.DataArray);
    //Your api call and save result value 
    EditorValue.Text = result;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Now I am working on it (which you mentioned above), If I have any doubt let you know

Comment: Hi Deep Soni, I try to install Xam.Plugin.FilePicker, this one no Dependency, this Package will apply to Android only, There is no option for iOS, is there any other package for file picker?

Comment: @P.Thiyagu In `iOS` you have to select from the Files it only get files or images from the `Files.` In simulator you are not able to check and add files. Try to do it with real device and one more thing it also work with `UWP`

Comment: I found a solution, I given MaxResponseContentBufferSize=256000 that's why i could not post userrest, so What i done is, increse MaxResponseContentBufferSize =25600000 after that it is working fine                                                                            Note: i am not using xam.plugin.filepicker instead of using xam.plugin.media for pick single image and convert to byte

Comment: Great @P.Thiyagu